# Hibernate one to many new insert new without link table

Tags: hibernate, annotations

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_customer")
public class Customer {
    public Customer() { }

    @Id
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int customerId;
    @Column(name="store_name")
    private String storeName;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="tb_customer_pic", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="person_id")})
    private List<Person> picList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<Person>(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Person.class));

    //getter setter truncated
}
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_person")
public class Person {
    public Person() { }

@Id 
@Column(name="person_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int personId;
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personEnt", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PhoneList> phoneList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<PhoneList>(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PhoneList.class));

//getter setter truncated
}
```

PhoneList.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_phonelist")

public class PhoneList {
    public PhoneList() { }

    @Id
    @Column(name="phonelist_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    private int phoneListId;
    @Column(name="provider")
    private String providerName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person personEnt;

    //getter setter truncated
}
```

CustomerController.java
here's where i get the json

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomer(Locale locale, Model model, @ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer cust) {
        logger.info("[saveCustomer] " + cust.toString());

        if (cust.getCustomerId() == 0) { customerManager.addCustomer(cust); }
        else { customerManager.editCustomer(cust); }

        model.addAttribute(Constants.PAGEMODE, Constants.PAGEMODE_LIST);
        model.addAttribute(Constants.ERRORFLAG, Constants.ERRORFLAG_HIDE);

        return "redirect:/customer";
    }
```

json generated from the cust.toString()

```
Customer [customerId=0, storeName=aa, bankAccList=[], picList=[Person [personId=0, firstName=a, lastName=a, addressLine1=a, addressLine2=a, addressLine3=a, emailAddr=a, photoPath=, phoneList=[PhoneList [phoneListId=0, providerName=b, phoneNumber=b, phoneStatus=b, phoneNumRemarks=b], PhoneList [phoneListId=0, providerName=b, phoneNumber=b, phoneStatus=b, phoneNumRemarks=b]]]]]
```

CustomerDAOImpl.java

```
public void addCustomer(Customer cust) {
logger.info("[addCustomer] " + "");

Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.persist(cust);

logger.info("Customer added successfully, Customer Details = " + cust.toString());
```

}

table configuration

tb_customer
tb_person
tb_customer_pic (for linking)

tb_person
tb_phonelist (without linking table, tb_phonelist columns contains person_id for linking)

Customer entity has many person as PIC and each person has many phonelist/number. so far i'm able to save(insert) until all table but for tb_phonelist, the person_id column  always null when saving, what am i doing wrong here?
thanks

Comment: Paste the code that creates the cust instance i.e. the method implementation that calls addCustomer()

Comment: thanks for the fast reply  
here's the json for customer :  
Customer [customerId=0, storeName=aa, bankAccList=[], picList=[Person [personId=0, firstName=a, lastName=a, addressLine1=a, addressLine2=a, addressLine3=a, emailAddr=a, photoPath=, phoneList=[PhoneList [phoneListId=0, providerName=b, phoneNumber=b, phoneStatus=b, phoneNumRemarks=b], PhoneList [phoneListId=0, providerName=b, phoneNumber=b, phoneStatus=b, phoneNumRemarks=b]]]]]

Comment: So for the above json string you just use gson to convert it to java object? Paste the complete method in your question.

Comment: question updated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because the phone instances do not have the person object set. After you construct the Customer instance from the json, you should loop through the phoneList from the person and set the person object into each of the Phone objects.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomer(Locale locale, Model model, @ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer cust) {

        for(Person p : cust.getPicList()) {
          for(PhoneList phone : p.getPhoneList()) { 
             phone.setPersonEnt(p);
          }
        }

        logger.info("[saveCustomer] " + cust.toString());

        if (cust.getCustomerId() == 0) { customerManager.addCustomer(cust); }
        else { customerManager.editCustomer(cust); }

        model.addAttribute(Constants.PAGEMODE, Constants.PAGEMODE_LIST);
        model.addAttribute(Constants.ERRORFLAG, Constants.ERRORFLAG_HIDE);

        return "redirect:/customer";
    }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: but the person_id actually an auto generated one (see the person.java). does it mean i can't do the insert in 1 go (just call persist(cust))

Comment: It can do. Have set the person instance in the phone object?

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont understand, can you provide the changes that i need to do? tq

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks very much it works well. But after consideration i'm changing it to use bridge table and use @ManyToMany annotation.

Comment: sry new to stackoverflow :)